# running variable created by taking data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i am making a site with clickable images that link to a link for instance youtube.com.
I want to make 1 function for all links so i came up with putting the variable name inside the data-id and then trying to run the variable.

Any ideas why this won't work?

It does print $youtube but how can i use that printed variable.

```js
     $(document).ready(function(){

    $youtube = "https://www.youtube.com/";
    $gmail = "";


    $(".linkicon").click(function(){
        $element = "$"+ $(this).data("id");
        window.open($element,"_self");
    });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="linkicon" data-id="youtube">
        <img class="linkimg" src="assets/img/youtube.png">
        <p class="text-center white">YouTube</p>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you cannot dynamically access variables in the manner you're attempting.

To workaround this you could store the `data-id` as the key of an object and have the URL as the value. Then you can use bracket notation to access the object, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var links = {
    youtube: 'https://www.youtube.com/',
    gmail: ''
  }

  $(".linkicon").click(function() {
    var $element = links[$(this).data("id")];
    window.open($element, "_self");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="linkicon" data-id="youtube">
  <img class="linkimg" src="assets/img/youtube.png">
  <p class="text-center white">YouTube</p>
</div>
```

You should however note that this approach is completely non-compliant in terms of accessibility guidelines, as you're using a `div` as an element which triggers an action.

Also note that the `$` prefix on JS variables is generally used to denote that the value is a jQuery object, not a string.